# "remote: Error deploying…" while running "git push appengine master"

Tags: git, google-app-engine

I've set up git deployment [according to Google's guide](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/push-to-deploy). After running `git push`, I get this:

[image]

I checked my appspot URL (http://webplatformdaily.appspot.com/) but it responds with a 500 Server Error. What am I missing?

**The source code of the app I'm trying to deploy is [on GitHub](https://github.com/simevidas/webplatformdaily-site/tree/py).** It could be that the issue is with the `app.yaml` or `gae.py` files which I copy-pasted from the [HTML5 Boilerplate server configs](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-gae).

Comment: Are you testing local first with dev_appserver? I gave it a quick spin and it failed to locate index.html. Can you see anything in your logs at https://appengine.google.com/logs?app_id=s~webplatformdaily ?

Comment: You have an error deploying, so I would check that you can successfully deploy using appcfg.  Its possible to have stuff misconfigured and not be able to deploy in general.

Comment: @NachoColoma Thing is, I'm not a Python dev. I don't even have it installed locally. Google AppEngine seems to use it by default, so I just copy pasted the server config files from HTML5 Boilerplate. **Update:** I went with the "pure static site" approach: I deleted the `gae.py` file from my repo, and edited `app.yaml` accordingly. The updated repo is on GitHub (link is above). Could you check if you can locate index.html now? *** The logs are empty. Btw, the link to appcfg on that page returns a 404.

Comment: @TimHoffman Unfortunately, I cannot test that. I don't use Python. I just copy pasted the server config files from HTML5 Boilerplate. Thanks for the info. I'm trying to slim the config files down to make it work.

Comment: I would invest the time and download the appcfg.py  and run it locally.  Trying to develop for appengine without testing locally is going to be a world of hurt.  You are unlikely to succeed.

Comment: @TimHoffman But there *is* no Python in my web site. It's just a static site. If somebody can provide me with the config (i.e. `app.yaml`) or explain why the one provided by HTML5 Boilerplate may have an issue, I would be grateful. But I do not have time to go into Python right now.

Comment: Well at least show us you app.yaml.  How do we guess what is wrong.  How do even test that your static site will work, are you going to ask 100 questions about each statuc file or static dir handler you have missed.  I mean really even testing static sites is going to be much easier if you test it locally. This doesn't mean you are writing python, just testing with something that looks like production - any other way is madness.

Comment: @TimHoffman As I've stated in my question, the source code of my site (including the `app.yaml` file) is on GitHub. Go here: https://github.com/simevidas/webplatformdaily-site/tree/py

Comment: @TimHoffman Of course I'm testing my site locally. It's just a HTML page and a bunch of JavaScript that runs in the browser.

Comment: But you are not testing it with the dev server which will interpret your app.yaml as per the production env.  Some other web server will not replicate the handler registration/regexes etc....

Comment: You app.yaml is 250 lines long, surely you would test it locally to work out if the mapping is correct.  - You have 2 issues I see, 

1. failure to deploy and you won't test an alternate deploy method which my provide better error messages telling you what is wrong. 

2. You have an insanely complex app.yaml which you won't test locally and want to test by deploying -  good luck

Comment: @TimHoffman As I've also stated in my question, the app.yaml file is from HTML5 Boilerplate's server configs. It's a boilerplate which defines the basic settings. There shouldn't be issues with this file.

Comment: And yet you have problems. I have suggested some paths of inquiry that could help you solve your problem.  People are rushing to provide asnwers.

Comment: @TimHoffman And I've explained why it's not reasonable for me to take those paths. I've got a busy work schedule and I don't have time to invest hours and days trying to set up a functional Python environment from scratch. Those things take time. I have no interest in Python and I won't invest time into this. I'll repeat: If somebody on this forum with experience in Python is kind enough to look into my source code (which I'm fully providing on GitHub) and see if there's an issue with the `app.yaml` file, I'll be grateful.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas did you get any solution? I'm trying this only with a raw app (the basic files generated by AppEngineLauncher) and it doesn't work. The project runs with dev_appserver and I'm also able to deploy it via command line. Thank you!

Comment: It's working now! The problem was I had an empty index.yaml file, I mean, I have to find exactly what's the connection between no indexes and _git push_. Anyways, it works if I delete this file.